# Getting access denied when accessing Azure Web App via token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-web-app-service

We are testing locking down an API hosted on Azure Web Apps by using the built-in Azure Web App Authentication/Authorization with Azure Active Directory.

We are calling POST `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantIDhere}/oauth2/v2.0/token` with the following parameters in Postman:

```
grant_type: password
client_id: {ID}
username: {username}@{tenenat}.onmicrosoft.com
password: {password}
scope: https://{webappname}.azurewebsites.net/.default
client_secret: {secret}
```

Below is the response I get:

```
"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"https://{webappname}.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation https://{webappname}.azurewebsites.net/.default","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"{TOKEN HERE}"}
```

So I take that token and try and access the webpage by passing the token in the header and I get the below error using POST:

https://{webappname}.azurewebsites.net/api/url

```
Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN HERE}
```

Response (401 Unauthorized)

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

I have spent days trying everything I can find. What am I missing?? As soon as I turn off authorization needed for the web app, I get the expected result. But using the grant_type: password, I CANNOT get in! I have a feeling its related to the scope, but I cannot find documentation on what I need here for this. Any ideas?

The user is able to manually login to the webpage and pull the data, so it is not a permission issue. It has something to do with the token I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using v2.0 endpoint, the scope should be `{your_client_id}/.default`. Replace  `https://{webappname}.azurewebsites.net` with the client id/application id for your API app in Azure AD.

[image]

**Edit**:

As Wayne said, you could also set `scope` as `{your_client_id}/User.Read` to get access token.

Comment: Actually, as you're using ROPC flow, the permission should be delegated permissions. So, we still should use specific scopes for delegated permissions, NOT `<AppIdentifier>/.default`. If you obtain application permissions, you can use `<AppIdentifier>/.default` as the scope.

Comment: That worked thanks! I also realized I was sending the bearer token in the Body tab and not the Header tab. After changing that as well, I got the expected result! Thank you for your help!